# What is the functional difference between using an EntityManager directly and JpaRepository

Tags: spring, jpa

For some time I have been using the following directly in service classes:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

As an alternative, I could build a AbstractDao extended by a PersonDao.  These classes would use the EntityManager

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {

    private final Class<T> persistentClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDao(){
        this.persistentClass =(Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public T findByKey(PK key) {
        return entityManager.find(persistentClass, key);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery( "from " + persistentClass.getName()).getResultList();
    }

    public void save( T entity ){
        entityManager.persist( entity );
    }
```

Is there any functional difference between these approaches - other than more code in the later?  What would cause me to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data in this case will cover what you have in the second example. Other frameworks will have similar approach hiding the EntityManager and providing you an out of the box API.

There is no difference (considering only the results) between two approaches and even your note *other than more code in the later?* is not true as I'm sure any framework will have tons of lines of code behind it to support the operations. :)

Comment: So the first code segment is the most appropriate approach when using Spring?

Comment: Not really _most appropriate approach_. We could have an analogy of you want to drive around, you can buy a car (spring data or other frameworks) or you can buy the bits and put your car together. Each case is a case. I use spring for all my development just because it works straight out of the box but also because I can configure for specific cases as well. You might need to get something up quickly then frameworks are the way to go but you might also need something very specific so you will need to build your own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it's really helped.  I have been slowly building my knowledge and appreciation of Spring.

Comment: I've been using spring for around 15 years. The platform provides everything you need. :)